# How do you find $\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j(j+1)}p\right)$,p = prime, where $\left(\frac{j(j+1)}p\right)$ is the Legendre symbol?

Tags: number-theory

I'm having trouble finding a pattern by calculating each step of the sum from $j=0$ to $j = p-1$.

Comment: Have you tried for some small values of $p$ to see what you get?