# Proving summations involving the Legendre symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, legendre-symbol

In the following, let $(\frac{a}{p})$ denote the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). Then

> Show that $$\sum _{a=1}^{p-2} \left(\frac{a(a+1)}{p}\right)=-1$$ for an odd prime $p$.

I was thinking of factoring out $a^2$, but…

> Show that $$\sum _{a=1}^{(p-1)/2} \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=0$$ for a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Are those quadratic residues?

Comment: Yes they are quadratic residues @BeniBogosel

Comment: Hint: Let $a^\ast$ be the inverse of $a$. Then $a(a+1)\equiv a(a+aa^\ast)\pmod{p}$, so $(a(a+1)/p)=(a^2((1+a^\ast)/p)=((1+a^\ast)/p)$.

Comment: It seems interesting can you be more explicit @AndréNicolas How does one approach these ones?

Comment: There is already an answer to the first question, on the hint side, but my answer would be just an expansion, so I prefer to omit it. For the second, we need to use the fact the prime is of the shape $4k+1$, and therefore $-1$ is a QR. Thus for any $a$ with $1\le a\le \frac{p-1}{2}$ we have $(a/p)=((p-a))/p)$. So the sum of the Legendre symbols from $1$ to $p-1$ is twice the sum of the Legendre symbols from $1$ to $\frac{p-1}{2}$. But the sum of the Legendre symbols from $1$ to $p-1$ is $0$ (that was the hint given).

Comment: You can find your first question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333704/sum-of-the-product-of-consecutive-legendre-symbols-is-1 (and in other posts linked to that one).

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 1):

The first question is answered in several other posts:

- [sum of the product of consecutive legendre symbols is -1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333704/sum-of-the-product-of-consecutive-legendre-symbols-is-1)
- [How can I prove these summations for the legendre symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341126/how-can-i-prove-these-summations-for-the-legendre-symbol)
- [How do you find $\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j(j+1)}p\right)$,p = prime, where $\left(\frac{j(j+1)}p\right)$ is the Legendre symbol?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216626/how-do-you-find-sum-j-0p-1-left-fracjj1p-right-p-prime-where)

For the second one, first you can notice that 
$$\newcommand\jaco[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \jaco ap = 0,$$
since this sum contains the same number of $1$'s and $(-1)$'s.

Using the fact that 
$$\jaco{p-a}p = \jaco{-a}p = \jaco{-1}p \jaco ap \overset{(*)}= \jaco ap$$
you can divide the above sum into two sums which are equal to each other and therefore they are both zero.

(Can you say why the equation denoted by $(*)$ holds?)

Answer (score 0):

Some **hints**:

1. $a(a+1)$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $\frac{a+1}{a}=1+a^{-1}$ is quadratic residue and then how many quadratic residu of the form $1+x$ with $x$ invertible are there?
2. How many quadratic residues are there in $\Bbb Z^*$ and how many non quadratic residue are there?